# Local hostname not displayed by script at boot

Tags: bash, debian, hostname

I have written a very simple bash-code which is trying to send the local hostname of the system to a php-page, basically using:
curl mypage.com/?hostname=$HOSTNAME

When I run this bash file "per hand", it is perfectly working. However, when started by rc.local, it does execute, but the hostname is working - the page only receives a request, but without the GET-value. (i.e. ?hostname= )

I have tried adding "export HOSTNAME" before the curl-command, but it still does not work.

Does any of you have an idea why this is happening?

My system is Raspbian, and the php-page works.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that /bin/sh is not a symlink to bash on your system. Use

```
curl mypage.com/?hostname=$(hostname)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Also, it seems that I have to use the full path for curl. (thus /usr/bin/curl)